# Find spectrum of linear operator $T_f$ on $L^2$ such that $T_fg=fg$

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $\mathbb R$. For any $f\in L^\infty(\mu)$, define $T_f\in B(L^2(\mu))$ by $T_fg=fg$. What is the spectrum of $T_f$?

If $\mu(f=\lambda)>0$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb C$, then $(T_f-\lambda I)\unicode{x1D7D9}_{\{f=\lambda\}}=0$, hence $T_f-\lambda I$ is not invertible.
If $\mu(f=\lambda)=0$ and $\mu(|f-\lambda|<1/n)=0$ for large $n$, then $(f-\lambda)^{-1}$ is well-defined and lies in $L^\infty$, and $T_{(f-\lambda)^{-1}}(T_f-\lambda I)=(T_f-\lambda I)T_{(f-\lambda)^{-1}}=I$, hence $(T_f-\lambda I)$ is invertible.

How to deal with other cases?

Comment: Spectrum is the closure of the essential range of $f$.